# Send file from rest web service

Tags: java, file, rest

I want to consume a file(pdf file created using iText library) from rest web service written in java to android client. I think one way is encoding the file to base64 string and then sending string. I am searching in the web for any other better approach but unable to find.
Is there any other better approach to accomplish this. please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you return binary? You can use InputStream/OutputSteam directly. Encoding to base64 is not the only way. Your question is unclear. Do you need to send file to REST service or consume it at REST.

Comment: We services, especially the REST web services are not suited for such bulk data transfer. You question is not very clear whether your problem is just send file and you are considering Rest web services as one of the option OR there is already a REST web services and you want to use that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this file is likely to be just one part of a larger response, base64 is usually the best option.